# How to make all the windows in an iOS app support rotation?

Tags: ios5, rotation, xcode4.3

I am knew to this whole app development for the iOS platform. Does anyone know how to make all the windows support rotation for the iOS 5 platform. I am currently using XCode 4.3.2. Either a coding or a storyboard explanation would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Return the orientations you want to support, like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPotrait;
}
```

You will see this function at the bottom of the code when you create a new view controller.